# Prevent bash expansion of tilde ("~") when assigned to a variable

Tags: bash

I am trying to make my life easier by creating an SCP (Secure Copy) function in my bashrc:

```
scpcloud() {
        CP_STR="$(whoami)@${REMOTE_HOST}:"
        CP_STR+=$1
        CP_STR+=" $2"
        scp $CP_STR
}
```

Ideally, I should be able to type something like `scpcloud ~/myfileonremote.png myfileonlocal.png`.

However, a problem arises in this usage because Bash expands special characters:

`scpcloud ~/myfileonremote.png myfileonlocal.png`

becomes:

`kenny@remote.host.com:/Users/kenny/myfileonremote.png myfileonlocal.png`

Which is not what I want. I want the tilde (and any other Bash word-expansions) to be literally sent to the remote host. So ideally, my command would become:

`kenny@remote.host.com:~/myfileonremote.png myfileonlocal.png`

I've attempted to rectify the issue through means of quoting:

```
CP_STR+='$1'
CP_STR+="$1"
```

To no avail. Is there a solution that can accomplish this?

Comment: most reliable is to avoid using ~ at all in scripts. I think it's just for convenience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't build up a string (or at least, a *single* string) and expect word-splitting to break it correctly into two arguments.

```
scpcloud() {
    scp "$(whoami)@$REMOTE_HOST:$1" "$2"
}
```

Further, you need to quote the tilde, as the shell expands it before `scpcloud` even runs.

```
scpcloud "~/myfileonremote.png" myfileonlocal.png
```

Comment: That's a shame that we can't prevent tilde expansion inside the function itself. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try escaping the tilde key.

```
 scpcloud \~/myfileonremote.png myfileonlocal.png
```